# What does operations per second mean in layman terms for Simple Statistics NPM package?

Tags: performance, npm

I'm using [simple-statistics](https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics) in my application. It's [github](https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics/tree/master/benchmarks) contains some performance benchmarks, which states that:

> Numbers are in operations per second.

Googling "Operations Per Second" yields information on "floating point operations per second" which I don't think is relevant to these benchmarks.

My thoughts are that perhaps it means, the number of operations (variance, covariance etc.) the library can calculate in each second. If that's the case, the page doesn't state how large the test data set is. (I'm most probably missing something).

**What are the below numbers trying to convey in layman terms? Is it merely to rank the libraries?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think he has simply made a table of how many operations per second his own machine can execute for each function of each library, including his own. "Operations per second" is not an standardized or objective measure, it is just meant to show his libraries performance relative to the same functionality in other libraries.